# C++ Compilation error in overloading

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, overloading

The following code compiles fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass()
    {
        x.resize(2);
        x[0] = 10;
        x[1] = 100;
    }
    std::vector<int> getValue()
    {
        return x;
    }
    const std::vector<int>& getValue() const
    {
        return x;
    }
private:
       std::vector<int> x;
};


int main()
{

    MyClass m;
    std::vector<int> y = m.getValue();
    for(int i=0; i<y.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout<<y[i]<<std::endl;
    }

    const std::vector<int>& z = m.getValue();
    for(int i=0; i<z.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout<<z[i]<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I change the "std::vector getValue()" to a more correct version (since the function is supposed to change the  object) by adding "const" (std::vector getValue() const) it gives the following compilation error.

```
error: 'const std::vector<int>& MyClass::getValue() const' cannot be overloaded const std::vector<int>& getValue() const
```

Why is it so?

I have used "gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)"

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe     passing the &(address operator )in return    :                                                                     const std::vector<int>& getValue() const
    {
        return &x;
    }

Comment: Post the version that does not compile.

Comment: @RSahu the first code is correct, the described change later in the post breaks the code

Comment: Please provide the other piece of code that gives the error.

Answer (score 5):

You can't define two functions with the same name, which differ only in return type. So define function with different name, for example:

```
std::vector<int> getValueCopy() const;
```

Answer (score 3):

By adding `const` to the first function you render calls to `getValue` ambiguous: What is the difference between those 2 functions:

```
std::vector<int> getValue() const;        // 1
const std::vector<int>& getValue() const; // 2
```

Well, they are the same, except for the return value, but wait! You can't overload based on the return type in C++! It wouldn't make sense, most calls would be ambiguous:

```
std::vector<int> y = m.getValue(); // which one? It can be 1, it can be 2 (std::vector<int>
                                   // is not a better match than const std::vector<int>&)

const std::vector<int>& z = m.getValue(); // same as above

m.getValue(); // which one?
```

But also, what is supposed to be the difference between the two?

The first one is 100% safe, while the second one is not: one could store a reference to `x`, and it becomes a dangling reference if the object gets destroyed. And so I would say that you get rid of the second one, if possible.

Comment: I understand that C++ does not allow overloading functions which differ only in return type to avoid ambiguity. But in this example, is there really ambiguity exists? const std::vector<int>& z = m.getValue() clearly requires to return the address whereas the first one requires to return a copy!

Comment: @Soo Yes, there really is ambiguity: you can initialize a `const&` with an rvalue (the first `getValue`) *or* with another reference (the second `getValue`). Both are possible, and the compiler doesn't know which one you want to call (even if it's obvious to you). Due note that if you were to write `std::vector<int>& v = m.getValue()` there is no ambiguity because you can't initialize a reference with an rvalue, and so the second overload is chosen.

Answer (score 1):

your problem is that you didn't understand functions overloading concept

when you overload function The definition of the function must differ from each other by the types of argument or the number of arguments in the argument list.

You can not overload function declarations that differ only by return type.

in your functions :

```
std::vector<int> getValue() const 

const std::vector<int>& getValue() const
```

it only differ in return type so it will be not considered as overloaded functions

best way to correct your error is to change your second function name to `getValuev2()`

or change arguments of one of the functions.

you can read more about overloading in C++ :
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_overloading.htm

Comment: Actually the functions you posted are valid overloads. The trailing `const` makes all the difference.

Comment: @juanchopanza in overloading concept it isn't valid because it only differ in return type,but why the  trailing `const` makes all difference?

Comment: Yes, meaning the two functions *don't* only differ in return type.

Comment: @juanchopanza thank you,I didn't  notice this point i modified my answer.